# How to minimize a variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on a prolog project that I have to minimize one of the variables.

For example:

```
foo(A,B):-
 ...
 someFunction(A',B',C),
 ...
```

someFunction will do something to obtain the value of C. There are many combinations of  A' and B' such that there are many Cs available.

For example:

```
A'1, B'1 -> (C=2)
A'2, B'2 -> (C=0)
A'3, B'3 -> (C=10)
A'4, B'4 -> (C=5)
```

I want it to try every combination and choose A'2 B'2. What should I do?

Comment: What's `A'` and `B'`? That's not really valid syntax... How do you know which permutations to try? I imagine the first two arguments of `someFunction()` are expected to be bound numeric arguments, correct?

Comment: Sorry for unclear. 
You can imagine A and B to be lists of coordinates for two players in a chess game. 
A' and B' are the updated lists of coordinates after one pass. There are many possible moves. 
C represents the number of coordinates that the next player can place and win the game. 
I want to minimize the chance of losing the game by minimizing C. Then A' and B' will become the desired board in next round.

Comment: What you've shown is pretty sparse as how your *predicate* (not *function*) works. Assuming you're predicate backtracks for each new result, you could use `setof/3` to capture all of the solutions of the form `C-(A,B)` for instance, which will sort in order of the term `C`, then just take the first element in the resulting list. Or you could recursively, at each new solution, keep the smallest of the two, which is classic minimize predicate behavior. Just a little effort searching this site for `[prolog] minimum value` or something similar should turn up lots of ideas as well.